# Is there any difference between Arjun Reddy and Kabir Singh?

Tags: remake, arjun-reddy, kabir-singh

I have recently seen the Hindi film *Kabir Singh* which is a remake of the Telugu film *Arjun Reddy*. But I was curious about how things go in *Arjun Reddy*. I mean is it a scene to scene copy or are there any adaptation differences between them? If yes then what are these differences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mostly, Kabir Singh is a scene to scene copy of Arjun Reddy mostly because the director is same and he is very particular about keeping his story consistent. But as Telegu version is 14 minutes longer than the Hindi version, some scenes have been removed. I am listing some of the major ones:

1. Shiva comes to Arjun with an NRI guy who came to Hyderabad to get married and seeing Shiva's sister. While meeting Arjun, he complained about typical Indian ladies in the plane and how they looked and which kind of girl he wanted to marry. Arjun told Shiva that this guy is objectifying women and is not suited for his sister. Arjun rejected him in front of him and tells him to leave.
2. Shiva tells his father about Arjun's habit of bringing ladies to his apartment for a one-night stand but failing and telling them his story and tragedy.
3. After Arjun's medical license gets canceled and he was spending most of the time at apartment drinking, Kamal comes with Shiva and Vidya to give him a wedding invitation. Arjun doubts that his girlfriend Keerti's parents have agreed. Shiva tells him that he is marrying Keerti and his parents have agreed. Arjun refuses to attend Kamal's wedding and accuses that Kamal is not worthy of love marriage. Kamal tells him that Arjun and Priti's love story is a high bar and Kamal's story is just a fluke and forces him to come by telling that he will not get married without Arjun. Shiva scolds Arjun that at least Kamal knows how to behave with girlfriend's parents and Arjun is the one who is unworthy. The scene ends with Kamal and Vidya leaving and Arjun kicking Shiva out of the apartment.

Apart from these, there are some minor changes like the house where all the friends were living during last year is on the beach and Arjun goes for a vacation in Europe and only Kamal visits him there.

Two addition scenes which are missing in Arjun Reddy, first, a boy's hostel scene. In Arjun Reddy, the entire group is living at a beach house from the start. And another, pubic hair removal scene which is only in Kabir Singh.

Overall, Kabir Singh is more polished than Arjun Reddy because of budget and as it's a 2nd attempt of the same director.

Answer (score 0):

To keep it short, In Kabir Singh, the main character was shown in a strange kind of god-like way towards his friends and family members. He could abuse them, throw them out of his house and even pick a fight with them, but in this movie, they showed his friends revolving around him like ants near a yummy food. His close friend Shiva on the other hand also was shown not doing anything to help his friend Kabir to show him how shallow he is.

On the other hand in Arjun Reddy movie, the protagonist is not shown as some sort of demi-god. In one scene, when one of Arjun's friend invites him to his wedding, Arjun bursts out on him saying 'he is an unworthy person for being chosen to be part of love marriage'. And the movie shows a well-depicted motivation of his friends trying to make him understand his envious/ bad side. They don't put Arjun on a pedestal, like Kabir Singh's friends do with him.

Aside from a few scenes, the film Kabir Singh is nothing more than a dubbed version of Arjun Reddy with new faces. For me personally Arjun Reddy was a better movie, as Vijay Deverakonda is way more convincing as Arjun than Shahid as Kabir. He manages to show variations in terms of emotions as compared to Shahid's one-note performance.